# access the edit function inside my controller

Tags: laravel

Hi guys new to laravel here. I am trying to edit my post and when i try to access the `edit` function in my controller i get this `error Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

> This is My route code

```
Route::resource('/article','PostController');
```

> This is my Controller

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{

    $post = Post::all();
    return view('article.edit',compact('post'));

}
```

> This is my View code

```
<a href="{{route('article.edit', $post->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-bordred wave-light"> 
<i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

> And solution ? Thanks in advance

Comment: `$post` is all the records in that table, not one single model

Comment: `all()` return a Collection (multiple models)

Comment: You should use find($id). Because, you want to edit not listing data.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing `collection` to your `view` instead of single post

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{

    $post = Post::all(); // this is a collection of posts
    return view('article.edit',compact('post'));

}
```

it should be:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    // here $post holds the instance of single/current post

    return view('article.edit',compact('post'));

}
```

Then in your `blade`

```
<a href="{{route('article.edit', ['post' => $post->id ])}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-bordred wave-light"> 
<i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
```

**Note:** Since you are passing `$post` as `instance` of the model so therefor you don't have to use `Post::find();` `laravel` will take care of that automatically at back-end

Thanks

Comment: that's didn't work still having the same problem !!

Answer (score 1):

When you use "all", you will get all data from post table. In edit function you get $id as a parameter.

```
public function edit($id)
{

    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('article.edit',compact('post'));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the variable `$post` holds a Laravel Collection. You have to iterate on that collection to access each post model.

```
// Returns a collection of posts model (think of 
// it as an array of posts)
$post = Post::all();
```

On your blade, use a `foreach` to iterate through each post.

**Edit**

I see that you already have an instance of post available, in that case just use this code

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    return view('article.edit', ["post" =>$post]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Post::all()` return a Collection (multiple Models)

You need to pass the id in the `edit($id) function` and then you can `find($id)`

```
 public function edit($id){
      $post = Post::find($id);
      return view('article.edit')->with('post', $post);
 }
```